# Trouble with a nonhomogeneous differential equation $ y''-3y'=1+x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find a general solution to:
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 3\frac{dy}{dx} = 1+x $$

Firstly I've found the complementary function, by solving the homogeneous version of the D.E above, and I've got that it's:
$$ y(x) = A + Be^{3x} $$

Now for the particular solution, I've tried $y=Px+Q \implies y'=P$ and $y''=0$, so subbing back into the D.E, I get:
$$
-3P = 1 + x \\
P = -\frac{1}{3}-\frac{x}{3}
$$
So $$y=(-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{x}{3})x = -\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{3}$$

Therefore my general solution is
$$ y(x) = A + Be^{3x} -\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{3}  $$

But this is not right, I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: If you look for a particular solution $y(x)=Px+Q$, your $P$ cannot depend on $x$... Try rather $y(x)=ax^2+bx$ for the particular solution.

Comment: @Did Is this because there is a constant in the complementary function and on the RHS of the non-homogeneous differential equation?

Comment: @Michael Yes. Suppose you just had the inhomogeneous equation $y''-3y'=1$. If you try to find a constant solution $y_p=c$ to the inhomogeneous equation, you get $c''-3c'=1$ which reduces to $0=1$.

Comment: @DavidH Alright thanks, it makes more sense now :)

Comment: It helps to split the equation into two parts and find the $Y_p$ for each one... $y''-3y'=1$ and $ y''-3y=x$

Comment: your $Y_h$ should be $y''-3y'=0$ and then change it to the characteristic equation $r^2-3r=0$... factoring out the r, we have $ r(r-3)=0$< so $ r=0,3 $ and those two are real roots. Therefore your $Y_h$ should be $c_1e^{0x}+c_2e^{3x} \rightarrow c_1+c_2e^{3x}$

Comment: Or, apply the general method explained there http://math.stackexchange.com/q/780608/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0$ is a root for the characteristic equation then the particular solution take the form
$$ax^2+bx^2+c$$
so substitute this polynomial in the differential equation and find the coefficients $a,b$ and $c$.

**Remark**

If we have an ODE
$$ay''+by'+cy=P(x)e^{\alpha x}$$
then to find a particular solution there are three cases:

- If $\alpha $ isn't a root to the characteristic equation so a particular solution to the ODE take the form
  $$Q(x)e^{\alpha x}$$
  where $Q$ is a polynomial with $\deg Q=\deg P$.
- If $\alpha $ is a simple root to the characteristic equation so a particular solution to the ODE take the form
  $$Q(x)e^{\alpha x}$$
  where $Q$ is a polynomial with $\deg Q=\deg P+1$.
- If $\alpha $ is a root to the characteristic equation with multiplicity $2$ so a particular solution to the ODE take the form
  $$Q(x)e^{\alpha x}$$
  where $Q$ is a polynomial with $\deg Q=\deg P+2$.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that equation.

Comment: I edited my answer to give the general result.