# ODE $y''+ 9y = 6 \cos 3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have this equation: $y''+ 9y = 6 \cos 3x$

$$
   m^2 + 9m = 0\\
   m(m + 9) = 0\\
   m_1 = 0;\\
   m_2 = -9;\\
   y_h = c_1 + c_2 e^{-9x}\\
   r(x) = 6\cos3x\\
   y_p = K\cos3x + M\sin3x\\
   y'_p = -3K\sin3x + 3M\cos3x\\
   y''_p = -9K\cos3x - 9M\sin3x
$$
    Here is my problem

$$    
    -9K\cos3x - 9M\sin3x + 9(K\cos3x + M\sin3x) = 6\cos3x
$$

as you can see it is obvious that both cos and sin will cancel out, and i don't think i can multiply $y_p$ with $x$ just like  i did with my other problem to change the equation.

so what am i doing wrong here?

Thank you :)

Comment: Your characteristic equation for starters.

Comment: @Mike what is characteristics equation?

Comment: $m^2+9m$ is not correct.

Comment: It should be $m^2+9 =0$.

Comment: oh you're right, didn't notice it was y' sorry for that will recheck it now

Comment: And when you get it right, you'll find the same "multiply by $x$" idea works just fine.

Comment: Third question in a row on exactly the same theme (how to find particular solution of linear second order ODE with constant coefficients and simple right-hand side). There are *methods* to do that...

Comment: @Did as you can see i have answered everything up to the point of Yp where i then get confused as i am not that familiar with all the methods yet same with the multiply by x

Comment: @GerryMyerson will try it then :)

Comment: Let me repeat: instead of trying to be clever each time, why not learn once and for all [the correct method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)? I recommend to read and digest sections 3.1 and 3.2 of the linked page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the characteristic equation $m^2+9=0$ has been solved, yielding the roots $m=\pm3\mathrm i$ and the solutions of the linear equation as linear combinations of the functions $x\mapsto\cos(3x)$ and $x\mapsto\sin(3x)$, the method of [variation of the parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) recommends to look for the general solution of the full equation as
$$
y(x)=a(x)\cos(3x)+b(x)\sin(3x),
$$
for some functions $a$ and $b$ solving the system
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}a'(x)\cos(3x)+b'(x)\sin(3x)&=&0\\ -3a'(x)\sin(3x)+3b'(x)\cos(3x)&=&6\cos(3x)\end{array}\right.
$$
This is a Cramer system, solved by
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lclcl}a'(x)&=&-2\cos(3x)\sin(3x)&=&-\sin(6x)\\ b'(x)&=&2\cos^2(3x)&=&\cos(6x)+1\end{array}\right.
$$
hence there exists some constants $(\alpha,\beta)$ such that
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}a(x)&=&\tfrac16\cos(6x)+\alpha\\ b(x)&=&\tfrac16\sin(6x)+x+\beta\end{array}\right.
$$
Plugging this in $y(x)$ and using the identity $$\cos(6x)\cos(3x)+\sin(6x)\sin(3x)=\cos(3x),$$ one sees finally (with no sweat...) that the general solution is
$$
y(x)=\tfrac16\cos(3x)+x\sin(3x)+\alpha\cos(3x)+\beta\sin(3x).
$$
Thus, $\alpha=y(0)-\frac16$ and $\beta=\frac13y'(0)$. An alternative formulation is
$$
y(x)=\tfrac16\cos(3x)+x\sin(3x)+\varrho\cos(3x+\omega).
$$

Comment: this is certainly shorter than the one taught to us, were we need to get the values of y", y', and substitute that on the original equation simplify and get the values for M and K to get the general solution. My answer using that Yp formula is different from your answer though i will recheck my answer.